# My global resource designer file is empty when I add culture to the file name

Tags: localization, asp.net-3.5

I am writing a asp.net web application with multi-language support. I want to add a resource to the App_GlobalResources file called "GlobalStrings". When I name the file GlobalStrings.resx, everything is fine. But when I add a file called GlobalStrings.en-US.resx the designer file behind it is empty (no text at all) an nothing appears in intellisense. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The deal is that there must be one resource file (default) without culture added.

Comment: I'd like to add that the default resource file should have all the data from the culture-specific one. That way, you can have two or three culture-specific resource files, and one default. If the culture specific file for the current ui culture have the property you're trying to access, you'll get this one. Otherwise, you'll get the default.